# Same Constraints but error for a bigger matrix size

Tags: matrix, constraints, cplex

Matrix Z is a set of decision variables. I am creating constraints for each elements of matrix Z:

constraint# 18 : the sum of each element Z of each row must be equal to 1.

constraint# 19 : the sum of each element Z of each column must be equal to 1.

There are two scenarios, namely: Total_T = 6 and Total_T =14

When I run the CPLEX model with size of matrix Z = 6 x 6, the solver ran well. However, with exactly the same code for size of matrix Z = 14 x 14, the solver was error.

It seems the constraint#19 did not work well.

What happened and what do I need to do?

Here is the code:

```
Z = np.empty((Total_T, Total_T), dtype = object)
for k in range(Total_T):
    for i in range(Total_T):
     Z[k][i] = mdl.binary_var(name='Z' + str(k+1) + str(',') + str(i+1))

#Constraint 18
#mdl.add_constraints(mdl.sum(Z[k][i] for k in range(Total_T)) == 1 for i in range(Total_T))

# Constraint 19
mdl.add_constraints(mdl.sum(Z[k][i] for i in range(Total_T)) == 1 for k in range(Total_T))
```

Error:

[image: Screenshot Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of CPLEX are you using?
With 22.1 the following code:

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model
import numpy as np

mdl = Model()
Total_T = 14

Z = np.empty((Total_T, Total_T), dtype = object)
for k in range(Total_T):
    for i in range(Total_T):
     Z[k][i] = mdl.binary_var(name='Z' + str(k+1) + str(',') + str(i+1))

#Constraint 18
mdl.add_constraints(mdl.sum(Z[k][i] for k in range(Total_T)) == 1 for i in range(Total_T))

# Constraint 19
mdl.add_constraints(mdl.sum(Z[k][i] for i in range(Total_T)) == 1 for k in range(Total_T))

status = mdl.solve()

print(status)
```

works fine and produces the expected diagonal:
solution for: docplex_model1

```
Z1,1=1
Z2,2=1
Z3,3=1
Z4,4=1
Z5,5=1
Z6,6=1
Z7,7=1
Z8,8=1
Z9,9=1
Z10,10=1
Z11,11=1
Z12,12=1
Z13,13=1
Z14,14=1
```